# Spring bean to google guice conversion

Tags: java, spring, guice, guice-3

Below snippet is taken from [here](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/source/browse/trunk/sample/jpa-hibernate-maven/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml). My question is how can I have this binding in Guice.

```
<bean id="searchProcessor" class="com.googlecode.genericdao.search.jpa.JPASearchProcessor">
            <constructor-arg ref="metadataUtil" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="metadataUtil" class="com.googlecode.genericdao.search.jpa.hibernate.HibernateMetadataUtil"
            factory-method="getInstanceForEntityManagerFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

I need to @Inject JPASearchProcessor (see below). I am completely new to Guice.

```
@Inject
public void setSearchProcessor(JPASearchProcessor searchProcessor) {
        super.setSearchProcessor(searchProcessor);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the module configuration you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by myself

A provider class HibernateMetadataUtilProvider is create to provide HibernateMetadataUtil

```
    package core.models.dao;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

    import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;

    import com.google.inject.Inject;
    import com.google.inject.Provider;
    import com.googlecode.genericdao.search.MetadataUtil;
    import com.googlecode.genericdao.search.jpa.hibernate.HibernateMetadataUtil;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class HibernateMetadataUtilProvider
            implements Provider<MetadataUtil> {

        @Inject
        private EntityManagerFactory emf;

        @Override
        public MetadataUtil get() {
            return HibernateMetadataUtil.getInstanceForEntityManagerFactory((HibernateEntityManagerFactory) emf);
        }
     }
```

Another class JPASearchProcessorProvider is created which will inject JPASearchProcessor

```
    package core.models.dao;

    import com.google.inject.Inject;
    import com.google.inject.Provider;
    import com.googlecode.genericdao.search.MetadataUtil;
    import com.googlecode.genericdao.search.jpa.JPASearchProcessor;

    public class JPASearchProcessorProvider implements Provider<JPASearchProcessor> {

        @Inject
        private MetadataUtil mdu;

        @Override
        public JPASearchProcessor get() {
            return new JPASearchProcessor(mdu);
        }

    }
```

Then in our inject class we can simply bind these providers

```
    public class AppInjector extends AbstractModule {


        @Override
        protected void configure() {


            /*
             * JPA Bindings
             */
            bind(JPASearchProcessor.class).toProvider(JPASearchProcessorProvider.class);
            bind(MetadataUtil.class).toProvider(HibernateMetadataUtilProvider.class);


    }
```